# Full output hidden on console

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I don't get full output of the following code I made.

For Example:

```
DriveSpace                         : {174, 0, 98, 171...}
```

Notice the ellipses (...) after 171. It is skipping the rest of the output after that. You can run the following script to see my output.

```powershell
#Start of script
$cpu            = gwmi -Class Win32_Processor | Select-Object NumberOfCores,NumberOfLogicalProcessors
$memory         = gwmi -class win32_physicalmemory | Select-Object {[math]::truncate($_.capacity / 1GB)}
$HostDescription= gwmi -Class Win32_OperatingSystem
$fqdn           = "$env:computername.$env:userdnsdomain"
$OS             = (gwmi Win32_OperatingSystem)
$OSarchitecture = (gwmi Win32_OperatingSystem)
$disk           = gwmi Win32_LogicalDisk | Select-Object DeviceID, volumeName, {[math]::truncate($_.size / 1GB)}
$timezone       = [System.TimeZone]::CurrentTimeZone
$fire           = netsh advfirewall show publicprofile | select-string state
$firematch      = $fire -match "off"
$slmgrResult    = cscript c:\windows\system32\slmgr.vbs /dli | Select-string "License Status"
$activation     = $slmgrResult -match "Licensed"
$apps           = gp HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* |Select DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate
$network        = Get-WmiObject win32_networkadapterconfiguration -filter "ipenabled = 'True'" | select-object IPAddress, DefaultIPGateway, DNSDomain, IPSubnet
$props = @{            
    NumberOfCores               = $cpu.NumberOfCores
    NumberOfLogicalProcessors   = $cpu.NumberOfLogicalProcessors
    Memory                      = $memory.{[math]::truncate($_.capacity / 1GB)}
    HostDescription             = $HostDescription.Description
    FQDN                        = "$env:computername.$env:userdnsdomain"
    OS                          = (gwmi Win32_OperatingSystem).Name
    OSarchitecture              = $OSarchitecture.OSArchitecture
    DriveLetters                = $disk.DeviceID
    DriveLabels                 = $disk.volumeName
    DriveSpace                  = $disk.{[math]::truncate($_.size / 1GB)}
    timezone                    = [System.TimeZone]::CurrentTimeZone.StandardName
    FirewallDisabled            = $firematch
    Licensed                    = $activation
    Applications                = $apps
    IPAddress_Gateway_DNSDomain_subnet = $network.IPAddress, $network.DefaultIPGateway, $network.DNSDomain, $network.IPSubnet
    }
New-Object PSObject -Property $props
#End of script
```

Comment: You have a real issue with the output of and definition of `$disk`. You should show us what you want it to look like. As of now `DriveSpace` would be an array of Free Space of _all_ the disks on the host system. PowerShell is truncating that to save console space. You could cast it to string but at that point the data would appear to be useless. Look at `$disk` while in the same PowerShell session and you will see it is a complex object. I think in the definition you meant to use a calculated property.

Comment: I would look at the output of the other properties as well. What do you plan on doing with this data. Need to be careful as putting this to file might not look exactly as you see it on screen.

Comment: `$FormatEnumerationLimit=-1`

Comment: Hi I only want the output to not truncate it. I want it to gimme the full output. I am very new to powershell and i just wanna be able to verify a machines configuration without having to check each configuration manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an official answer as I think the OP needs to be clear on what output he is expecting. This is a start nonetheless

While I have not found official documentation to support this you are just seeing how PowerShell handles console output. Consider the following example which is a collection of varying sizes of arrays.

```
[pscustomobject]@{
    data = "1","2","3","4","5"
}
```

Would produce the following list style output.

```
data : {1, 2, 3, 4...}
```

Notice the fifth element of the `5` property now has the ellipses. The data is still there. It has just been truncated on the console to make the output more terse and easier to read. In this case it seems folly to do so but with some objects complicated output PowerShell has to draw the line somewhere.

**Prevent the ellipses**

As [PetSerAL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4003407/petseral) pointed out you can just use the following line of code before your output.

```
$FormatEnumerationLimit=-1
```

If you look at [about_Preference_Variables](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/hh847796.aspx) you will see that, by default, this is set to 4. That would support the output you are seeing. Set that value to something higher or -1 and see if it helps.

**Other Potential Issues**

Like in my comments I want to draw attention to the variable you created called `$disk`. The output is below. **Note** this is from my own machine and wont match yours. Still, you should get the picture

```
DeviceID volumeName      [math]::truncate($_.size / 1GB)
-------- ----------      -------------------------------
C:                                                   111
D:       Data                                        499
E:       Multimedia                                 1362
F:                                                     0
G:       CentOS 7 x86_64                               3
M:       Media                                      2794
Z:                                                     0
```

Without any other information I can only assume that you want a series of free space values to display. Given that we could break those results out of the array by casting them to string. Also want to update the line that populates the variable.

```
$disk = gwmi Win32_LogicalDisk | Select-Object DeviceID, volumeName, @{Label="Size(GB)";Expression={[math]::truncate($_.size / 1GB)}}
```

Gives us the following in $disk`

```
DeviceID volumeName      Size(GB)
-------- ----------      --------
C:                            111
D:       Data                 499
E:       Multimedia          1362
F:                              0
G:       CentOS 7 x86_64        3
M:       Media               2794
Z:                              0
```

Then when you build your hashtable you can cast the array to a single space delimited string like this:

```
DriveSpace                  = [string]($disk."Size(GB)")
```

Fairly sure there will be more questions to come from this but it is at least a start. Welcome to SO. It is always a good idea when possible to show us desired output in cases like this so we know what you are trying to achieve. Even if you think it is obvious.

**Side notes**

You have other properties other that `$disk` that might have the same issues like `Applications` which is a complex object. If you do have issues with those as well solving this one might get you in the right direction.

You have many calls to `gwmi Win32_OperatingSystem`. You should save the results of that into a variable that you can refer to whenever you need it. Right now you are losing time calling it and getting the same results. For example:

```
$wmiOS = gwmi Win32_OperatingSystem
```

Comment: Here is the current output after i changed my $disk value to what you have mentioned above.
i am only posting the 2 outputs where the output is truncated.
DriveLabels                        : {, $null, Backitup, Multimedia...}
DriveLetters                       : {C:, D:, E:, F:...}
If there is no way that i can get these info without them being truncated with the current method then i will move on to some other method of pulling such info using powershell.

Answer (score 0):

This is the default formatting of Powershell at work, as provided by `Out-Default`. It is truncating the DriveSpace array to display in a table in your console, but the information is still there. For example, if you type:

`$props.DriveSpace`

... you will see the full array displayed. The default formatting behaves differently when it's handling a simple array as opposed to when it's handling a complex object like the `$props` one you've created.

See also:
[How Powershell Outputting and Formatting REALLY works](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/04/30/how-powershell-formatting-and-outputting-really-works.aspx)